# Getting precise DOM TREE for clicked element

Tags: jquery, tree

I'm trying to get precise DOM TREE up to clicked element.
If you try it you will see it works. But not exactly right. It doesn't separate click .container first DOM from second DOM element.
What should I do to get precise DOM tree to the selected element ?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJoVYo

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('*').click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    createDOMTree(el);
  });

  function createDOMTree(element)
    {
        var parents = element.parents();
        var count = parents.length - 1;
        var tree = '';

        for(i=count;-1 < count--;i--) {
            var element = $(parents[i]);
            tree += getElementDOM(element);
        }

        return tree;
    }

    function getElementDOM(element)
    {
        var dom = element.prop('nodeName');
        var id = element.attr('id') ? '#'+element.attr('id') : '';
        var classes = element.attr('class') ? '.' + element.attr('class').replaceAll(' ', '.') : '';
        var index = $(dom + classes).index($(dom + classes));
        var eq = (index > 0 && index != 0) ? ':eq('+index+')' : '';

        if(dom === 'BODY')
        {
            eq = '';
        }

        return dom + classes + eq + ' ';
    }
      String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
    };
});
```

Comment: `It doesn't separate click .container first DOM from second DOM element` Can you explain what you mean by that, as the problem is not obvious.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You can see exactly same 2 html .containers with it's child elements. I want DOM Tree to display which exactly .container and it's child element was clicked

Comment: can you explain to me this beautiful for loop `for(i=count;-1 < count--;i--) {`?

Comment: @user1876234 I see `HTML BODY DIV.container DIV.imtestingyou UL ` which is correct. Still unsure what the issue is. It may be more beneficial if you told us the output you expect when clicking the different elements.

Comment: i think you want something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPVrbO?editors=1111

Comment: Let's say I click first .container last LI element then the result should be like this:
`HTML BODY DIV.container:eq(1) DIV.imtestingyou:eq(1) UL Li:eq(4)`
If I click second .container, result should be like this:
`HTML BODY DIV.container:eq(2) DIV.imtestingyou:eq(1) UL Li:eq(4)`
I hope you get the idea

Comment: @user1876234 you script doesn't get the inner most elements / the li-s right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your index to:

```
var index = element.index();
```

and if you want precision

```
 if(element.siblings().length) {
    var eq = ':eq('+index+')';
  } else {
     var eq = (index > 0 && index != 0) ? ':eq('+index+')' : '';
  }
```

to get the li's you need to call getElementDOM on the clicked element

`var inner = getElementDOM(element);`

and then append it to the end of the tree `tree+= inner;`

use `>` operator to further differentiate your elements

```
if(dom != "HTML") dom =  "> "+dom;
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPVrbO?editors=1111)

Comment: Already tried this before. It's not going to work in some circumstances. ( More complicated HTML )

Comment: can you provide me with this edge cases?

Comment: @user1876234 Please do your part to progress this page toward a system-recognized resolution.  This volunteer cannot improve the answer without feedback from you.